# Resizing table's height dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Can someone suggest a way to change a table heights as per the content of a array? If an array has 1 data element then the table should show only one cell and if the array has 5 data elements or more then it should show that number of cells.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour anyway?

Comment: yes thats the deafult way but i am fixing the size of table but that size of table  should vary as per the data in array

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that default height of row is 44px, then you can calculate table height like this

```
int heightTable = 44 * [array count];
```

If you have another row height, then check `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. If your table also contain header/footer/sections, then check `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForFooterInSection` methods.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change the cell height, check-out [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) tutorial.

To change the `UITableView` height, you can do:

```
CGRect r = [tableView bounds];
[tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(r.origin.x, r.origin.y, r.size.width, r.size.height + 48)];
```

Comment: i dont want to resize the cell height but the complete table height